# What does this summation mean in relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, tensor-calculus

Equation 1.2 of ['t Hooft's Introduction to General Relativity](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/lectures/genrel_2010.pdf) gives the *Lorentz transformations*:

$$
(x^\mu)' = \sum\limits_{\nu = 1}^4 {L^\mu}_\nu x^\nu
$$

Is this the sum of four square matrices each one multiplied by a column vector? Or is this a single square matrix multiplied by a single column vector?

Comment: It the sum of (matrix components * vector components). This is another notation for matrix * vector multiplication. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation

Answer (score 2):

$L^\mu_{~\nu}$ is a collection of sixteen numbers which you can represent as a single matrix. $x^\nu$ is a collection of four numbers which you can represent as a single vector.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a square matrix multipled by a column vector, which gives you another column vector.